# WMI - Performance Data NonAnonymousUsersPerSec

Tags: c#, iis, wmi, performancecounter, wmi-query

I want to monitor my IIS (SharePoint Farm) with WMI. I am trying to get the following information from the system:

- CurrentConnections
- NonAnonymousUsersPerSec
- AnonymousUsersPerSec

My problem is that I want the same data as in the "Reliability and Performance Monitor" (perfmon) when I add the \Web Service(_Total)\Anonymous User/ses and \web Service(_Total)/NonAnonymous Users/ses to the monitor.

This monitor is showing me nearly 20 NonAnonymous users per second and 0 Anonymous. 
I think that these values are correct. The number of connection is the same, in the perfmon-monitor and the WMI query.

But the value for the CurrentUser is totaly different to the value in the monitor.

How can I get this data with WMI querys?

[Win32_PerfFormattedData_W3SVC_WebService class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
SelectQuery queryCurrentUser = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_W3SVC_WebService WHERE Name LIKE \"_Total\"");
```

- CurrentConnections : ~150
- NonAnonymousUsersPerSec : 0
- AnonymousUsersPerSec : 0

[Win32_PerfRawData_W3SVC_WebService class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
SelectQuery queryCurrentUser = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_W3SVC_WebService WHERE Name LIKE \"_Total\"");
```

- CurrentConnections : ~150
- NonAnonymousUsersPerSec : ~150000
- AnonymousUsersPerSec : ~2000000

Code:

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + stringServer + "\\root\\CIMV2");

//PerfRawData query
SelectQuery queryCurrentUser = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_W3SVC_WebService WHERE Name LIKE \"_Total\"");

//PerfFormattedData query
SelectQuery queryCurrentUser = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_W3SVC_WebService WHERE Name LIKE \"_Total\"");

ManagementObjectSearcher currentUsers = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, queryCurrentUser);
ManagementObjectCollection currentUsersCollection = currentUsers.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in currentUsersCollection) 
{
Console.WriteLine("CurrentConnections {0}", queryObj["CurrentConnections"]);
Console.WriteLine("NonAnonymousUsersPerSec {0}", queryObj["NonAnonymousUsersPerSec"]);
Console.WriteLine("AnonymousUsersPerSec {0}", queryObj["AnonymousUsersPerSec"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

The `Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications` class.

The values are in `RequestsPerSec` and `AnonymousRequestsPerSec`